# Emacs syntax highlighting for custom LaTeX comment environment

Tags: emacs, syntax-highlighting, auctex

I have defined a custom comment environment (through `\usepackage{verbatim}`):

```
\newenvironment{customComment}[1]
    {
    \noindent{\textsc{Commented bloc}: #1}}
    \comment}
        Commented block
    {\endcomment}
```

What I want to do is to highlight the content of the \begin...\end{customComment} either:

1. as an already existing environment (`font-lock-comment-face` maybe but haven't found any working example); or
2. through a complete font/background etc. customization.

Already tried the `defvar...` solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16338466/emacs-auctex-macros-fontification) and (for a similar *command* this time) [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11844936/emacs-auctex-custom-syntax-highlight/11848400#11848400).

Would be great if you found a solution that only needs editing the `.emacs or adding a`.el` (I've got a load of these customComments).

Comment: Is your goal to highlight everything between begin and end, similar to what AucTeX does for bold or italics?  E.g.,  **\begin{customComment}** `How do I highlight everything between begin and end?` **\end{customComment}**

Comment: Yes it's what I'd like but more as AucTeX does for `equation`

(couldn't find a way to get `begin...end` for neither bold nor italic btw)

Answer (score 2):

In the tex-mode that's built into Emacs you could do that by adding your environment to `tex-verbatim-environments`.

Comment: Ten years later, this is still helpful. I needed to get emacs to stop subscripting `identifiers_with_underscores` when using the "minted" package for adding color to code.

Answer (score 1):

To the extent that the original poster (or anyone else) may be interested in highlighting the text that appears between opening/closing LaTeX codes, below are a few examples.  The active ingredient is a regexp `(\\(.\\|\n\\)+?\\)`, which could be something else that is also similar, but would need to effectively do the same thing.  The following examples are set up to highlight text appearing between quotation marks that LaTeX artists frown upon, a bold command, an underline and a double underline using a tex package called `ulem`, bold and underline, and I threw in a begin/end document example so that the original poster (or anyone else) can combine the examples to make his / her own.

**NOTE**:  As the definitions become more complex and tend to overlap other definitions, the order in which they appear may be critical -- i.e., one definition may trump another.

```
(font-lock-add-keywords 'latex-mode (list

  (list (concat "\\(\"\\)\\(\\(.\\|\n\\)+?\\)\\(\"\\)")
    '(1 lawlist-super-orange t)
    '(2 lawlist-super-cyan t)
    '(4 lawlist-super-orange t))

  (list (concat "\\(\{\\)\\(\\\\bf\\)\\(\\(.\\|\n\\)+?\\)\\(\}\\)")
    '(1 lawlist-regular t)
    '(2 lawlist-purple t)
    '(3 lawlist-bold t)
    '(5 lawlist-regular t))

  (list (concat "\\(\\\\uline\\|\\\\uuline\\)\\(\{\\)\\(\\(.\\|\n\\)+?\\)\\(\}\\)")
    '(1 lawlist-green t)
    '(2 lawlist-regular t)
    '(3 lawlist-underline t)
    '(5 lawlist-regular t))

  (list (concat "\\(\{\\)\\(\\\\bf\\)\\(\\\\uline\\)\\(\{\\)\\(\\(.\\|\n\\)+?\\)\\(\}\\)\\(\}\\)")
    '(1 lawlist-regular t)
    '(2 lawlist-red t)
    '(3 lawlist-blue t)
    '(4 lawlist-regular t)
    '(5 lawlist-bold-underline t)
    '(7 lawlist-regular t)
    '(8 lawlist-regular t))

  (list (concat "\\(\\\\begin\\|\\\\end\\)\\(\{\\)\\(document\\)\\(\}\\)")
    '(1 lawlist-super-orange t)
    '(2 lawlist-super-SeaGreen t)
    '(3 lawlist-super-HotPink1 t)
    '(4 lawlist-super-SeaGreen t))

   ))


(defvar lawlist-regular (make-face 'lawlist-regular))
(set-face-attribute 'lawlist-regular nil
  :background "white" :foreground "black")

(defvar lawlist-bold (make-face 'lawlist-bold))
(set-face-attribute 'lawlist-bold nil
  :background "white" :foreground "black" :bold t)

(defvar lawlist-bold-underline (make-face 'lawlist-bold-underline))
(set-face-attribute 'lawlist-bold-underline nil
  :background "white" :foreground "black" :bold t :underline "black")

(defvar lawlist-underline (make-face 'lawlist-underline))
(set-face-attribute 'lawlist-underline nil
  :background "white" :foreground "black" :underline "black")

(defvar lawlist-bumble-bee (make-face 'lawlist-bumble-bee))
(set-face-attribute 'lawlist-bumble-bee nil
  :background "black" :foreground "yellow" :bold t :underline "red")

(defvar lawlist-red (make-face 'lawlist-red))
(set-face-attribute 'lawlist-red nil
  :background "white" :foreground "red" :bold t)

(defvar lawlist-blue (make-face 'lawlist-blue))
(set-face-attribute 'lawlist-blue nil
  :background "white" :foreground "blue" :bold t)

(defvar lawlist-green (make-face 'lawlist-green))
(set-face-attribute 'lawlist-green nil
  :background "white" :foreground "green3" :bold t)

(defvar lawlist-orange (make-face 'lawlist-orange))
(set-face-attribute 'lawlist-orange nil
  :background "white" :foreground "orange" :bold t)

(defvar lawlist-purple (make-face 'lawlist-purple))
(set-face-attribute 'lawlist-purple nil
  :background "white" :foreground "purple" :bold t)

(defvar lawlist-pink (make-face 'lawlist-pink))
(set-face-attribute 'lawlist-pink nil
  :background "white" :foreground "pink" :bold t)

(defvar lawlist-super-orange (make-face 'lawlist-super-orange))
(set-face-attribute 'lawlist-super-orange nil
  :background "white" :foreground "orange" :bold t :underline nil)

(defvar lawlist-super-cyan (make-face 'lawlist-super-cyan))
(set-face-attribute 'lawlist-super-cyan nil
  :background "white" :foreground "cyan" :bold t :underline nil)

(defvar lawlist-super-blue (make-face 'lawlist-super-blue))
(set-face-attribute 'lawlist-super-blue nil
  :background "white" :foreground "blue" :bold t :underline nil)

(defvar lawlist-super-red (make-face 'lawlist-super-red))
(set-face-attribute 'lawlist-super-red nil
  :background "white" :foreground "red" :bold t :underline nil)

(defvar lawlist-super-purple (make-face 'lawlist-super-purple))
(set-face-attribute 'lawlist-super-purple nil
  :background "white" :foreground "purple" :bold t :underline nil)

(defvar lawlist-super-HotPink1 (make-face 'lawlist-super-HotPink1))
(set-face-attribute 'lawlist-super-HotPink1 nil
  :background "white" :foreground "HotPink1" :bold t :underline nil)

(defvar lawlist-super-SeaGreen (make-face 'lawlist-super-SeaGreen))
(set-face-attribute 'lawlist-super-SeaGreen nil
  :background "white" :foreground "SeaGreen" :bold t :underline nil)
```

Comment: Thanks lawlist,
implemented your solution but it only changes the color of `begin`, `end`and `customComment`: no change in the font-face inside the environment.

Comment: That is correct.  This is an example, not your exact solution.  You will need to combine the last part for the begin and end, with the part above using the special regexp in the other three examples.  The special regexp is what tells Emacs to highlight everything in that area.  The regexp you are looking for looks like this:  `(\\(.\\|\n\\)+?\\)`  You can also change the three examples that use that special regexp, to be custom tailored to your exact situation.

Comment: Thanks! I had tried your last example, replacing `document` by `customComment`.
Will try wirting the right regexp for my case ASAP.